# Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts?

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests

```java
public class QbPaymentConnect {
    
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void QbCustomers(string recordId){
        opportunity op = [select name from opportunity where id=:recordId];
        system.Debug(op);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('POST');  
        request.setEndpoint('callout:qbOnline/v3/company/4620816365248252120/customer?minorversion=40');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');  
        request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        string jsonString='{"DisplayName" :"'+op.name +'"}';
        request.setBody(jsonString);
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(request);
        system.debug('res:'+res.getBody());
        //system.debug('Status Code: '+res.getStatusCode());
        QuickBookWrapperClass cus = new QuickBookWrapperClass();
        cus = (QuickBookWrapperClass)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), QuickBookWrapperClass.class);
        String custId = cus.Customer.Id;
        op.customerId__c=custId;
        update op;
        system.debug('customer Id: '+custId);
        
    }
}
```

```java
global class mockCalloutQB implements HttpCalloutMock{
    global HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req){
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        res.setBody('{"Customer": {"Id": "67"}}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

```java
isTest
public class testQB {
    @testSetup static void setup() {
        Opportunity op =   new Opportunity(Name = 'TestOpp',closeDate = System.today(),stageName='Prospecting');        
        insert op;
    }
    
    @isTest 
    private static void QbCustomerTest(){
        Test.startTest();
        opportunity op = [select Name,id from opportunity where name like 'TestOpp'];
        string recordId = op.Id;
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new mockCalloutDrive());
        
        QbPaymentConnect.QbCustomers(recordId);
        Test.stopTest();

        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit Test Error: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225856/unit-test-error-methods-defined-as-testmethod-do-not-support-web-service-callou). Is there any process that runs on Opportunity creation? If so, also the `@testSetup` method requires a mock.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a mock. See [Testing HTTP Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing.htm):

> By default, test methods don’t support HTTP callouts, so tests that perform callouts fail. Enable HTTP callout testing by instructing Apex to generate mock responses in tests, using `Test.setMock`.

See also [Testing HTTP Callouts by Implementing the HttpCalloutMock Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm). Like much Salesforce documentation, it uses `global` where it is not necessary, and you should instead use `public`. But all you really need to know is that you must implement the `HttpCalloutMock` interface. Once you've set up such a class, you pass an instance to `Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MyMock())`.

Comment: its already there in the code by the name mockCalloutDrive.

Comment: Is the code in your question your actual code or paraphrased? Seems like you must be causing a callout before your mock is set. You could try moving it to the very top of your test method to verify...